# printing output in assembly x86

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I have this code:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
    arry BYTE ?
    prompt1 BYTE "Enter first hex number: ",0
    prompt2 BYTE "Enter second hex number: ",0
    prompt3 BYTE "The sum is ",0
    prompt4 BYTE "The sum is out of range ",0
    prompt5 BYTE "Convert again? [y/n]: ",0
    prompt6 BYTE "First number is invalid ",0
    prompt7 BYTE "Second number is invalid ",0

.code
main PROC
    ReadInput:
        L1:
            mov edx, OFFSET prompt1
            call writeString
            mov edx, 0
            call readHex
            call Crlf
            mov ecx, eax
            jmp L3
        L2:
            mov eax, 0
            mov edx, OFFSET prompt2
            call writeString
            mov edx, 0
            call readHex
            call Crlf
            mov ebx, eax
            mov eax, 0
            jmp L4
        L3:
                cmp ecx, 0FFFFh
                JA L5
                JBE L2
        L4:
                cmp ebx, 0FFFFh
                JA  L6
                JBE addInt
        L5:
                mov edx, OFFSET prompt6
                call writeString
                            mov edx, 0
                call Crlf
                jmp L1
        L6:
                mov edx, OFFSET prompt7
                call writeString
                mov edx, 0
                call Crlf
                jmp L2

    addInt:
        clc
        mov ax, cx
        add ax, bx
        JC printError
        jmp convert

; convert hex to string
    convert:
           mov ecx, 0
           mov esi, 0
            mov si, 4
            mov cx, 10h

    convertDigit:
            dec si
            mov dx , 0
            div cx
            cmp dx, 9h
            JA  convertLetter
            add dx, 30h
            jmp printSucess

    convertLetter:      
            add dx, 37h
            jmp printSucess

    printError:
            mov edx, OFFSET prompt4
            call writeString
            call Crlf

    printSucess:
            mov arry[si], dl
            cmp ax , 0
            JNE convertDigit
            mov edx, OFFSET arry
            add dx, si
            call writeString
            call Crlf


    exit
main ENDP
END main
```

when I tried to print output i get this

Enter first hex number: ff

Enter second hex number: ff

1FEer first hex number:
Press any key to continue . . .

as you can see, there was a part of prompt1, `er first hex number` which stuck with the value of the sum `1FE`, why did this happen

the program loop edx register 3 times first time  the value is `E`, the second time is `F`, and the third time is `1`, then it get to writeString to print output, which seems to be what the program suppose to be doing, at this point the edx value suddenly jump to `00405911`, why did this happen?

thank in advance for the help

Comment: The address of edx when copying prompt1 toedx is he same as the address of edx when copying the sum to edx, leading to the sum to append and replace a part of prompt1, how can i make edx change to different address so, it will only output the sum without part of prompt1 added to it?

Comment: There is code missing.

Comment: no there is not I copy and paste everything

Comment: the address of `arry` is  `00405910` and the address of edx when prompting for entering first hex number is  `00405911` and when I add esi which is 1 to edx, the address of edx become 00405911 which cause the output to appear as `1FEer first hex number:`, instead of 1FE which is what I want. How do I change the edx address so that the output won't include prompt1 string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a NULL-terminator to the converted string. You could do that right before the `convertDigit` loop:

```
mov byte ptr [arry+4],0
```

By the way, you don't need `div` when you're dividing by a power of two (like 16). You can use the faster bitwise AND and shift instructions:

```
mov dx,ax
and dx,15   ; dx = ax & 15 (== ax % 16)

shr ax,4    ; ax = ax >> 4 (== ax / 16)
```

Comment: ah, thank you, I am not allow to use bit- wise operations on this assignment

Comment: may I ask what does `mov byte ptr [arry+4],0` do ? does it read the address only up to index 4?

Comment: In your loop you start out with `si` set to 4, which you then pre-decrement before storing any characters (so the highest address you'll write to is `arry+3`). So what that new instruction does is to place a NULL-terminator just after the last digit, so that `writeString` will know where the hex string ends.

Comment: You reserve only a single byte for `arry`, and then stuff 4 characters into it. Make your buffer bigger! (probably 5 bytes - to hold terminating 0) Also, after printing error (if that should happen) you fall through into `printSuccess` - probably not what you want...